# How to run the php file with firefox in vimrc configuration?

Tags: php, firefox, vim

I have set php command line  mode in vimrc configuration file.

```
nmap <F5> :!php %
```

It run the current php file when to press F5 key in php command line mode .

Now i want to run the current php file in firefox browser,how to map F6 to do the job?

```
nnoremap <F6>f :exe ':silent !firefox  "http://127.0.0.1/". "%"'<CR>
```

It can't run when to press F6 key.

Think to  Zach .
The command was changed into 
nnoremap f :silent !firefox "http://127.0.0.1/%"

The file  `test.php` was edited in vim ,my document root is `/var/www`,
when to press F6 and f ,the firefox opend.

http://127.0.0.1//var/www/test.php
Not Found

The requested URL /var/www/test_equal.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

The problem now is how to fix the "http://127.0.0.1/%" ,to change

```
 http://127.0.0.1//var/www/test.php  into   http://127.0.0.1/test.php
```

Here the current file is  /var/www/test.php (%).

Why my command can't run?

```
 nnoremap <F6>f :silent !firefox -new-window "http://127.0.0.1/"{expand('%:t')}
```

Comment: Try `nnoremap <F6>f :silent !firefox "http://127.0.0.1/%"<CR>`

Comment: The `%` sign expands to relative path of your current file (try `:!echo %` to see what it expands to). I'm not sure you want `%` in there, maybe you can find something more reliable in [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-special).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** It appears that sometimes creating a file in vim when you aren't in that directory to begin with (e.g. `vim /path/to/newfile.php` instead of `vim newfile.php` from within that directory) might change the value of `%`. In that case just grab the tail using `%:t`. So try this instead:

`nnoremap <silent> <F6>f :!firefox 'http://127.0.0.1/%:t' &<CR>`

---

**TL;DR: On Mac, Something like this should work:**

```
nnoremap <F6>f :silent !/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -new-window "http://127.0.0.1/<C-R>%" &<CR>
```

On Linux or Windows just replace the path to Firefox as required.

If you're getting `http://127.0.0.1//var/www/test.php` instead of `http://127.0.0.1/test.php` then you need the filename only and not the path. Try using `<C-R>%` instead like this (I'm referring to the path of my firefox installation directly):

```
nnoremap <F6>f :silent !/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -new-window "http://127.0.0.1/<C-R>%" &
```

If the `firefox` command is already setup, then continue as you are and use:

```
nnoremap <F6>f :silent !firefox "http://127.0.0.1/<C-R>%"
```

Of course, this assumes that your `firefox` command is correctly set up.

Also, *make sure that your file is saved with a filename* otherwise using `%` won't work.

For some people, using `:silent` still brings up the Hit Enter to contine prompt. If that happens try adding `&` at the end. E.g.:

```
nnoremap <F6>f :silent !/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -new-window "http://127.0.0.1/<C-R>%" &
```

Either way this will still ask you to press enter at the end. If this isn't what you want then add `<CR>` or `<ENTER>` at the end as well. Like this:

```
nnoremap <F6>f :silent !/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -new-window "http://127.0.0.1/<C-R>%" &<CR>
```

---

*Edit:* There does seem to be a rather annoying problem in that if you use this keybinding in Vim with a firefox process already running you get an error saying that only one version of Firefox can run at any one time. This happens regardless of whether or not you use `-new-window`, `-new-tab` or neither. It seems that [an old bug about this was reported back in 2010](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=393645) but I haven't been able to find anything more recent. I'll see if I can figure out a solution other than just killing Firefox if it's already running (which would be yucky).

Comment: I am still  getting http://127.0.0.1//var/www/test.php instead of http://127.0.0.1/test.php

Comment: Could you open the file and type: `:echo @%` and compare that with typing `:echo expand('%:t')`? Let me know but the first will probably give you the full path but the second should only give you the filename. If it does, then we can change things to work with that I reckon.

Comment: test.php is the result of :echo expand('%:t').

Comment: Try this one. If it works I'll update my answer. `nnoremap <silent> <F6>f :!firefox 'http://127.0.0.1/%:t' &<CR>`

Comment: stackover is  the best  than any book.